# Changing the values in columns of textField w.r.t one editable column

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a table in which there is an editable column for quantity and the value of the prices depends on the quantity entered by the user. A snapshot of the table is as follows :

[image]

Here, the prices are for just 1 quantity. I want the prices to change automatically when the quantity is changed by the user. I read about bindings and tried them, but have not been able to successfully implement them. I am not aware of the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the total to the qty*price

```
public class LineItem {
private final SimpleDoubleProperty price = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
private final SimpleIntegerProperty qty = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private final SimpleDoubleProperty total = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

public LineItem() {
    DoubleBinding db = new DoubleBinding() {

        {
            super.bind(price, qty);
        }

        @Override
        protected double computeValue() {
            return (price.get() * qty.get());
        }
    };
    total.bind(db);
}
//important! add getters and setters
}
```

In the same way if you just want to listen to qty changed you can add a listener in the LineItem constructor instead of binding.

```
qty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
   @Override
   public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number t1) {
       total.set(price.get()*qty.get());
   }
});
```

Your table should be made with an ObservableList of LineItem

```
ObservableList<LineItem> lines = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
TableView table = new TableView(lines);
```

That way when the underlying list changes the table also changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onEditCommit()` of the TableColumn to retrieve the value once the user has committed their changes and use that to update your table.

You first need to set the listener. Have a look at the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html

Update from the docs:

> Because the ObservableList object enables the tracking of any changes
>   to its elements, the TableView content automatically updates whenever
>   the data changes.

Comment: I have already tried that to update the value of the field, but it gets updated in the list and doesn't show in the table.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm has the answer i guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onEditCommit as shown

```
quantity.setOnEditCommit((evt) -> {
        evt.getRowValue().setQuantity(evt.getNewValue());
        int quanity = evt.getNewValue();
        int costPrice = evt.getRowValue().getCostPrice();
        int price = cosePrice * quantity
        evt.getRowValue().setPrice(price);
        tableView.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
        tableView.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
    });
```

This will refresh your table each time you change the quantity.